# Nuget package dynamic ConnectionString

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, nuget, asp.net-core-5.0

I'm currently working on a net core 5 project where we are going to build reusable nugets for this and future projects. For e.g. I'm going to build a nuget for the system logging part, but it has to be reusable and my question is then; How do I pass a connectionString in a proper and safe way from my main project to the Nuget?

Is it possible to set a configuration file in the main project where the nuget package is able to read it's connectionString. Let's say I have main **project A** and installing my Nuget, then I would like to get the Nuget's connectionString for the database from my main project. And later on when I'm going to reuse this project in **main project B**, I may have a different databas and connectionString for it.

Hope I made it clear what I'm looking for here...

- We're working with .Net Core and EF Core.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would read the connection string from configuration, and then pass it to the reusable service as a constructor parameter. Preferably by registering the reusable service in StartUp.ConfigureServices.

Comment: Okey, thank you! I'll try that out and reach back if it doesn't work!